# Django changing models field into views

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I everyone, I have a problem with a django's view. My goal is to change the 'execute' field into 'True' if newOrder is buy and there is some other sell order with a inferior price. And reverse for sell newOrders. I want to change the 'execute' field for the newOrder and also for the other order (in pairs). That's my code:

views.py

```
def order(request):
    form = OrderForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = OrderForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_order = form.save()
            if new_order.buy is True:
                sellOrder = Order.objects.filter(sell=True, execute=False, 
                            price__lte=new_order.price).first().update(execute=True)
                new_order.execute = True
                sellOrder.save()
            else:
                buyOrder = Order.objects.filter(buy=True, 
                           execute=False,price__gte=new_order.price).first().update(execute=True)
                new_order.execute = True
                buyOrder.save()
            new_order.profile = request.user
            new_order.save()
            return redirect('home')
    else:
        form = OrderForm()
    contex = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'app/new_order.html', contex)
```

models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    _id = ObjectIdField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    wallet = models.FloatField()

class Order(models.Model):
    _id = ObjectIdField()
    profile = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    datetime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    buy = models.BooleanField(blank=True)
    sell = models.BooleanField(blank=True)
    price = models.FloatField()
    quantity = models.FloatField()
    execute = models.BooleanField(blank=True)
```

But something goes wrong. This is the error:
AttributeError at /new_order/
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'update'

Answer (score 0):

sellOrder returns a count of updated rows, not the object updated

```
sellOrder = Order.objects.filter(sell=True, execute=False, 
                            price__lte=new_order.price).first().update(execute=True)
```

instead try

```
sellOrder = Order.objects.filter(sell=True, execute=False, 
                            price__lte=new_order.price).first()
new_order.execute = True
sellOrder.execute = True
sellOrder.save()
```

Comment: I have already try this but gives me error: AttributeError at /new_order/
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'execute'

Comment: Is it possible that the results of the sellOrder query is empty?

Comment: Mh no, there are some sell orders